# Syncronize new / modified files trought SFTP on Linux

Tags: backup, sftp

I only have a SFTP access on my NAS, on Lacie OS 3.X, (so exit rsync) and i want to backup it from a remote debian server.

The problem is that the NAS is 4TB and it can take a lot of time if i transfert all files everytimes.

Is there a simple way to do that, based on modification time and or file size in a small script or a command line ?

Comment: [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) already does this.

Comment: Yes, but it have to be on both sides isn't it ?

Comment: No, @dawud probably didn't read/understand your whole problem. There is ftpfs, and you can rsync anything for that.

Comment: @dawud Simpe rsync is not enough, he stated very clear, he has only ftp access. And rsync can't ftp.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. Take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp there are some alternatives cited there to use SFTP.

Comment: I saw csync, look fine but dead ? A way to install it on a recent debian ?

Comment: And i'm afraid to rsyncing a ftpfs mount, some files are very fat and i read that it retrieve the whole file to make the checksum.

Comment: I don't know that we can be of much help, you seem somewhat restricted. What type (make/model) NAS is it ?

Comment: It's a Lacie 2 Big NAS, on Lacie OS 3.x. Initial Thread here if you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346422/backup-a-lacie-2-big-nas-on-a-remote-linux-server

Comment: I succeed to install csync2, but reading the documentation, i'm not sure i can do it with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your NAS can be configured to perform [remote backups](http://manuals.lacie.com/en/manuals/2big-5big-nas-3/dashboard/backup#set-up-remote-backups) (which appears to be what you want). This line is of interest

... It can also be a third-party NAS compatible with rsync.

In your case, the *remote debian server* should be considered a NAS. I expect you can configure rsyncd on it and then configure the NAS to use it as a target.

Comment: I didn't know that Rsync can be used as a daemon. It work, Thanks a lot !